# Tern Eclipse IDE and JSP

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, jsp, tern

I have:

- Eclipse Mars.2
- Tern Eclipse IDE 1.2.0
- dynamic web project with one test JSP file:

  ```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <html>
    <body>
      <script>
         var x = {    
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
  ```
- JS validator set to external
- Tern/Validation - JSHint enabled

What I expect is that JSHint throw some error regarding unclosed bracket. But instead it validates whole JSP and throws error at first line:

```
[JSHint]: Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'
```

Can I do something to have JS validation only in script tag? Also same for HTML files?

Thanx.